# Keycloak user's active session information

Tags: spring-boot, keycloak

I'm using `keycloak` for `authentication and authorization`, I want to get the `active session` information of the users or the user, but I couldn't find such information in the docs.

If there is an active session belonging to the user, I want to prevent this user from deleting it, so I need such information.

If we can't get the active session information, I can accept a different alternative answer.
I am using `Spring boot` and `keycloak version 15.0.2`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can get this API

"Get user sessions for client Returns a list of user sessions associated with this client"

GET /{realm}/clients/{sessionId}/user-sessions?first={startIndex}&max={numberUser}

It is located in https://www.keycloak.org/docs-api/15.0/rest-api/index.html

This is demo

1. Get master admin token
   [image]
2. Get the list of "Account-console" client ID
   [image]
3. Get the it's users session
   [image]

It should be match with Keycloak UI's client session information
[image]

1. if you want to prevent a deletion session of user, remove assigned realm management role
   [image]

Then he/she can't call remove a user session API
"Remove a specific user session"
DELETE /{realm}/sessions/{sessionId}

Comment: "if you want to prevent a deletion session of user, remove assigned realm management role". yep, actually by default the normal users will have those roles anyway.